# How to call theWeb Service from Xamarin with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin, asmx

I'm new here and sorry for my bad english. I am developing a Xamarin APP for the first time and I want to call the Web Service. I don't get any Result from the Web Service but the following Exception:

```
ex.InnerException = {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
```

at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-...."

I've seen a lot of YouTube video and surfed the Internet for a long time, but I haven't found a solution.

This is my Web Service:

```
//web Service from ASMX project
public class WStest : System.Web.Services.WebService { 

    [WebMethod(MessageName = "Test", Description = "test")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Result))]
    public Result test() {
        Result result = new Result();

        result.msg = "test successful";
        result.flag = 1;
        result.userNum = "usernummer";

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is just a part of Xamrain Code

```
private void Butsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    WStest.WStest test = new WStest.WStest();

    test.testCompleted += Test_testCompleted;

    test.testAsync();   //call Web Service
   

    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

 private void Test_testCompleted(object sender, WStest.testCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = e.Result.msg;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException); //here I get the exception
            }
  
        }
```

and thanks for all Answers

Comment: Did you check the inner exception? I would suggest not using these old WCF style services, but make a REST API.

Comment: if that data come from a external service, He can't really create an API rest.
if you are on local, check firewall and windows defender.
have you tried to explore the end point with visual studio connected service ?
when you have the exception, call ex.InnerException to see what inside

Comment: thanks for the answer the innerExeption status is: "System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure"
and the InnerExeption is:
ex.InnerException = {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00014] in / Users / builder / jenkins / workspace / archive -...

i don't know what to do should I adjust something with Visual Studio?:)

Comment: this is a networking problem.  Have you tested that the server is reachable from the device/emulator using the browser?  Are you running a local server?  If so, is it setup to accept remote connections?